# Fix query to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update table from result another table.
I have some tables

```
   Table people

    |id|level| 
      1   0 
      2   0 
      3   0
```

and   Table games

```
|id | idman | win_or_lose | game |
    1     1        win        1
    2     2        lose       1
    3     1        win        2
    4     3        lose       2
    5     2        win        3
    6     3        lose       3
```

I need to create query which change level in table people.
I try to use this query. but it's wrong. Please Help me fix this query.

My query.

```
UPDATE people p, 
(select count(id) as count
from games where and idman = p.id and win_or_lose = 'win') g
SET p.level = g.count
```

Comment: `where and` => problem, `win_or_lose = "win"` => other problem `win_or_lose LIKE 'win'` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this like this: (**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c29e/1/0)

```
update people p join (select idman, count(*) as max_game
                        from games
                       where win_or_lose = 'win'
                       group by idman) x on p.id = x.idman
   set p.level = x.max_game
```

Comment: You would do this wrong. Player 2 has level 3 while he has won just one game. It shuould be `count`, not `max`

Comment: @dragoste it was my understanding that the game column ascended in accordance with whatever 'level' he was talking about (ie. like an online game having level 1, level 2, 3 etc. where you have to win the prior in order to get to the next). Anyway I've updated the answer given that it's just the number of wins.

Comment: wait, I don't think this is correct, as per example user 2 haven't won game 1 and 2 but directly the game 3. I think its the game wise point calculation.

Comment: @avisheks I doubt that's what he wants. If you correct the syntax of the query he's trying, since it doesn't run due to syntax errors, what he wants to run will put user 2 to level 1 (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d1be/1/0). However the above is more efficient because all of the counts are produced in the inline view in one shot, the query does not have to re-run for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this(I believe idman is the FK of peoples Id column)

```
UPDATE 
people 
JOIN (SELECT idman FROM games WHERE win_or_lose="win" GROUP BY game)a
  ON people.id=a.idman
SET level=level+1
;
```

If the same people wins several different games. The level counter will keep on increasing.

Comment: This is the right idea of solving this problem, but there's no need to `GROUP BY game`. It seems there's only one `win` row per game.

Comment: Yeah, GROUP BY can be omitted. Placed it just to make sure the counter wont be increased for the same game_id

Comment: It it not said that it should not be in such case. ;-) +1 anyway.

Comment: This does not appear to work, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da6ca/1/0 , user #1 shows a level of 1 but has 2 wins

Comment: yeah I see that, I think its the lazy loading

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE people p, 
(select count(id) as count
from games where idman = p.id and win_or_lose = 'win') g
SET p.level = g.count
```

just try this you have added and in where clause without any condition that will be causing problem otherwise you are correct.